# Different Builds for the same application

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios6, build

I am developing a product for a client and I have a problem.

The application will be sold to various customers only changing the interface the same (images - images.xcassets).

What is the best way to manage this? I do not want to duplicate the project for each client, but a way to manage builds of each, and the only change will be the bundle id and images.

My project is IOS 6.1>

Thank you.

Comment: This is what targets and the ability to duplicate a target is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Wain says, set up multiple build targets. Select your project in the navigator area, then select the current target in the list of targets, right click on it, and select "duplicate". That will create a new target that does exactly the same thing.

You'll need to change the bundle ID, app name, etc.

Then you would select your current asset catalog, select the view menu>utilties>file inspector and set the target membership to just the current target. Select your new target, add a new asset catalog, and set it's target membership to only include the file in the new target.

Repeat this process for each version of the app that you want to build.

Comment: Duncan C thanks for the detailed explanation, had found other places to use targets but did not know how. 

It worked perfectly for my current needs. If in the future I need to make some adjustment to the level of code is possible to identify which target the code? 

Thank you.

Comment: @DiêgoNunes Yes, you can select which target(s) each source code file will be included with. For finer control over specific lines of code within a particular file, you can use #ifdef / #else / #endif

Comment: The simplest thing to do is to use different versions of your source files and use target membership to include them in the different targets. If you want to run different code at the method level I guess you'd either need to check the bundle ID in code (messy), or select your target, go to build settings>preprocessor macros and add a preprocessor macro for that target and use #ifdef precompiler statements to conditionally compile code for the different targets. BTW, you should accept the answer, and up-votes are appreciated.